# Why won't my OCE c360 print on upgrade to 14.04

Tags: printing

Our office uses OCE c360 by Konica Minolta and the generic driver (PCL 5e) only prints black and white, so we use the Linux driver provided by Konica Minolta, but that won't print at all and sometimes makes the printer hang so that it needs to be unplugged.

In 13.10 it worked fine to have one printer as the generic B/W printer, and install a new printer using the KOC360opn.ppd and this was great (even though it would only print one sided). 
Upon upgrade to 14.04, the generic driver is unreliable and the KOC360 driver won't print at all.

Do I need a different driver?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Konica PPD, use the Generic - PDF option. When choosing the options, instead of using PCL5e, choose PDF and most if not all of the regular options for duplex, color, page size are all available and work well. 
It only took me 4 years to find it.

Comment: Yeah! 4 years is such a small period!